# event.target jquery: differences in syntax

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm going through David Turnbull's Second Meteor App (a to-do list app) tutorial and a different jquery syntax is used for similar events, and I don't quite understand why...

The first part involves a feature to add tasks:

html:

```
<template name="addTodo">
<form>
Create a task:
<input type="text" placeholder="Type a task here..." name="todoName" autocomplete="off">
</form>
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.addTodo.events({
'submit form': function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var todoName = $('[name="todoName"]').val();
  Todos.insert({
    name: todoName,
    completed: false,
    createdAt: new Date()
  });
 }
});
```

The second part involves editing tasks by using the keyup feature:

html:

```
<template name="todos">
{{> addTodo}}
<ul>
{{# each todo}}
    {{> todoItem}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
</template>

<template name="todoItem">
<li>
    <input type="text" value="{{name}}" name="todoItem">
</li>
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.todoItem.events({
 'keyup [name=todoItem]': function(event){
  var documentId = this._id;
  var todoItem = $(event.target).val();
  Todos.update({ _id: documentId }, {$set: {name: todoItem }});
  }
});
```

I tried to use the event.target query below in the second part (editing tasks), but it did not work:

```
var todoItem = $('[name="todoItem"]').val();
```

Why is that? In what cases do we use which?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple todoItems and they all have the same name. Instead, try `event.target.inputName.value` without jquery.

```
//event
Template.todoItem.events({
    'keyup [name=todoItem]': function(event){
        var documentId = this._id;
        var todoItem = event.target.todoItem.value;
        Todos.update({ _id: documentId }, {$set: {name: todoItem }});
    }
});
```

If it doesn't work, might be because your inputs don't have a unique id/class. It should work if you replace `<li></li>` with `<form></form>` (event.target) but don't think its the best solution. I'd probably add the id of each task to `<input>` like `id="{{_id}}"` and select element by using that id.